# C# Variance return type

Tags: c#, scala

I am new to C# and having some real problems trying to apply variance restrictions to template types. Maybe it's just not possible the only "Where" clause examples I can find from my research are more based on going the other direction (ie. "Is assignable from"). I've listed the Scala function I'm trying to emulate - the point is to insure that T is assignable to U (ie. T<:U) so the return value is a U no matter what. Any help or tips on C# variance is appreciated, thank you

```
interface Option<out T> // where T : class
    {
        T GetUnsafe();
        Option<X> map<X>(Func<object,Option<X>> f);
        U GetOrElse<U>(U u) where T:U  ;  //What is wrong here,how do I get U:>T ?

        bool IsSome { get; }
    }
```

Example from Scala Option[A]
final def getOrElse[B >: A](default: ⇒ B): B

As an update, here's a working version as a Static function - I just can't figure out if it's possible as a method

```
 static class Option
    {
        public static U GetOrElse<T, U>(Option<T> o, U defAns) where T : U
        {
            if (o.IsSome) return o.GetUnsafe(); else return defAns;
        }
```

Comment: For that to work you'd need to declare `U` on the interface instead of the method.

Comment: As noted, variance only works on type parameters for interfaces. And the constraint you want for the method isn't valid anyway (you can only constrain the type parameter of the method to inherit some class). That said, IMHO it is an awkward design to have a method like that. Why can't the method just return `T`? What good would it be for someone with an `Option<T>` in hand, to call a method `GetorElse<U>()` with a type parameter that may only be a base type of `T`? Your question looks very much like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @PeterDuniho I know this may look odd but it's not of my invention, scala does exactly this . Here's an example why U needs to be bounded this way - say this is object is Some<kitten>, but it's now been upcasted to a place in my code dealing with Option<Cat> without knowledge that anything is inside.  the call I place at that moment has to ensure  U is a supertype of the item inside or it would be totally wrong. Var Cat = myCat.getOrElse(new Cat).. if it had no bounds : Var Cat = myCat.getOrElse(123455) would be a problem

Comment: But if you just don't make the method generic, and return `T` instead of `U`, that scenario works fine too. The method _does_ have bounds already, as long as you use the `T` that's already there. There may be a scenario where there's just no other way to express that relationship and yet being able to provides some dramatically better way to implement the code. But the scenario you described with Cat/Kitten doesn't appear to be that.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you again for your time, so the reason why U has to come into play is the purpose of the function (ie the fallback value u.) I cant pass it a T because T is marked "OUT" and that would be a violation of variance.

Comment: All that means to me is that you've inappropriately applied covariance. You've promised your interface implementation only emits `T` values, and doesn't accept them, and yet you want the interface to include a method that clearly accepts a `T` value (after all, using `T` as the type parameter for that method would satisfy the constraint you want to use). I'm no Scala expert, but still...it would help if you would provide good [mcve] for both C# and Scala, the latter showing a _working_ example, and the former showing what you believe to be the non-working equivalent in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you seem to mix "generic variance" with "generic type constraints". Yes, C# unlike Java or Scala only supports inheritance-related type constraints in one direction: you can specify base class (but you can do something that neither Scala nor Java support such as `new` constraint). See [where (generic type constraint) (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) for some details. And since `T` is defined in the outer scope you can't put additional constraints to it in the inner scope. This is the reason why your example doesn't compile. Your second example with a static method compiles because C# compiler is smart enough to re-order generic types in your declaration so that it looks like you define constraint (for `T`) using already known type (`U`).

I'm not sure what is the real life usage of that design of `getOrElse` Scala method given the fact that `Option` is covariant i.e. if you want to get value of type `B` even though its actual type is `A` just declare your `var` as having type `Option[B]`. So I think it wouldn't be a big loss to not copy this bit of logic.

Generally I don't think you can easily copy such a code exactly preserving behavior from Scala to C# but for this particular case where this method has only one fixed implementation that you don't need to override, you can extend you static trick to use [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods):

```cs
public static class OptionHelper
{
    public static U GetOrElse<T, U>(this Option<T> o, U defAns)
        where T : U
    {
        if (o.IsSome) return o.GetUnsafe(); else return defAns;
    }
}
```

Because of additional `this` keyword before argument you can use it as if it was defined in the interface itself (a bit similar to default methods in Java 8 and what you can get using implicit conversions in Scala):

```
Option<string> o = ..;
object value = o.GetOrElse(new object());
```

Comment: Thanks, it would seem that static functions are the best way around these problems